# illegal option -- ? when copying

Tags: bash, unix

I have just started to work on a Imac macOS HighSierra and when trying to copy some files I keep getting the error:

I just made a `test` directory to clarify the issue:

The directory `test` contains:

```
file1.txt file2.txt folder1
```

Using the following command in the parent directory:

```
cp -R test/ .
```

I get this error:

```
cp: illegal option -- ?
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
   cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
```

According to manual page for cp, the -R argument means:

If source_file designates a directory, cp copies the directory and the entire subtree connected at that point.  If the source_file ends in a /, the contents of the
directory are copied rather than the directory itself.

Any suggestions as to why I get the error ?

I have bash version version 3.2.57(1)-release

----UPDATE---

According to comments to this issue, I provide some additional information:

1. `which cp` returns `/bin/cp`
2. `echo cp -R test/ .`returns `cp -R test/ .`
3. `set | grep cp` returns nothing
4. `cp --version` and `cp --help` returns `cp: illegal option -- ? usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory`
5. `man cp` returns the manual page but it doesn't seem to depict anything about the version except `BSD                            February 23, 2005                           BSD`

Comment: And what is the `-r` option supposed to do? Have you tried to read the manual page for `cp` (i.e. `man cp`)? What does it say?

Comment: Is there an oddly named file in directory_1?

Comment: Note that the BSD `cp` that ships with macOS discourages the use of `-r`: "Historic versions of the cp utility had a -r option.  This implementation
     supports that option; however, its use is strongly discouraged, as it
     does not correctly copy special files, symbolic links, or fifo's."

Comment: It might help if you provide the version of bash you're using (`bash --version`) and the listing from directory_1 (`ls ../directory_1`). The error message suggests you're providing `?` as an options to `cp`, so you want to figure out why it thinks you did that.

Comment: Please copypaste the exact command you ran. If you feel like you must replace the source and target names, please rerun the command to ensure it still gives the same error.

Comment: I have updated the question. Hopefully this will clarify

Comment: @locoto: As you're copying recursively, the contents of `folder1` (presumably a folder...) would also be of interest, as per stark's comment.

Comment: Can't replicate [here](http://tpcg.io/nyb72W). This is strange. This should work as you posted here. I think the problem is not related to the code you posted, it must something else. Do you run the command from the command line or in a script? Can you post the output of `cp --version`?

Comment: @KamilCuk. It is strange. It also worked perfectly fine on my macbook (same bash version). `cp --version` also outputs `cp: illegal option -- ?`.

Comment: @DevSolar: folder1 is empty. It is not a question of file types or odly named files, I think. Can it be that the `cp` command os not installed ? Nothing works with `cp. `mv` on the other hand, works fine.

Comment: @locoto: If `cp` were not installed, it would not be there to report the error... Please add four outputs: The one from `which cp` -- the one from `cp --version` (or whatever version information you can get from `cp --help` or `man cp`) -- the one from your `cp` command with an `echo` in front of it (e.g. `echo cp -R test/ .`) -- the one from `set | grep cp`. Just to make sure what exactly you're telling the shell, and what the shell is seeing. (You might want to double-check and unify your examples -- right now one is about `directory_1` and one about `test`, that is a bit confusing.)

Comment: @DevSolar: I updated the post with the information

Comment: @KamilCuk: I am running it from the command line

Comment: @chepner: If the use of `-r` is discouraged, what should I use in place ?

Comment: Thanks; this confirms that you're running (an old version of) BSD `cp`, not some script or alias with that name that somehow tinkers with the arguments. It also shows there is no funny business going on regarding parameter expansion. Though I have no idea why it's complaining...

Comment: `which`, as an external command, won't know if there is an alias or shell function shadowing a builtin. Use `type cp` to see if that is the case.

Comment: Since BSD `cp` doesn't support long option names, I'm not surprised that it prints a usage message for `--version` or `--help`, although I *am* surprised that the error message says `cp: illegal option -- ?` rather than `cp: illegal option -- -`.

Comment: @chepner: `type cp` solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS, change the cp commands as below examples

Ex 1.

```
"copy:schemas": "cp --parents schematics/*/schema.json ../../dist/my-lib/",
```

as

```
"copy:schemas": "find schematics -type f -name 'schema.json' -exec rsync -R {} ../../dist/my-lib/ \\;",
```

Ex 2.

```
copy:files": "cp --parents -p schematics/*/files/** ../../dist/my-lib/",
```

as

```
"copy:files": "find schematics/*/files/** -exec rsync -R {} ../../dist/my-lib/ \\;",
```

Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your issue:

```
cp -R test/* .
```

or:

```
cp -R test/* ./
```

By adding the asterisk, you mention that you are copying files, not a directory.